# Accessing Angular $Scope in web workers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-worker

What is a common practice for accessing angular $scope data in Web Workers?

I'm trying this in combination with the parallel.js library.

```
$scope.variant = 7;
$scope.final = 0;
var p = new Parallel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
log = function () { console.log(arguments); };

function fun(n) {
   $scope.final += n * $scope.variant;
};

p.map(fun).then(log)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Workers spawn a new thread, which results in a new instance of Angular app, so that code is never connected to your main app unless you find an external way to communicate with it (sessionStorage, localStorage, cookies, API call, etc.). But you need to pass in that $scope you want somehow.

But generally, I don't think it's a good idea having two threads working on the same $scope (even if you manage to do that). Web Workers are usually used for some heavy stuff that's indepented from the main app, and which results than you pass back to the main app for further use (think about rendering a super-complex image, then passing it back to the main app so you can use it as a background or something).

---

UPDATE

So here's brief example of probably the easiest approach. You won't be using Angular in the worker script, but loop over those files as plain as possible:

controller

```
var worker = new Worker('iterator.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
  $scope.final = e.data; // for example
  $scope.$apply();       // launch a digest cycle
}, false);
```

worker script

```
function iterate() {
    // iteration and data collection stuff here
    // send the needed data afterwards: 
    self.postMessage(collectedData);
}
```

You can also send parameters to the worker, and call the iterate function with arguments, etc.

I've taken the examples from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/ as guidelines to quickly show you the way to do it. Let the workers do the heavy stuff, and only pass back the data you need back to the app.

Comment: I'm looping through 50,000 files which ends up blocking the UI. I've tried async library, the timeout trick, custom iterators, can't seem to get anything to work where I format my angular data without blocking.

Comment: Reason I'm accessing so many files is I'm using Chromium Embedded Framework to create a desktop app which isn't subject to sandboxing.

Comment: What do you need from those files in the end?

Comment: Basically constructing an object with properties like folderPath, fileCount, fileSize, and filtering by extension (i.e. ['mov', 'mp4', 'mpg']

Comment: Perfect! Then see my updated answer on how to return exactly that data.

Comment: Perfect! I love this new pattern.